How to Place a Button on Top of a Video Overlay in MindAR and A-Frame
I have an image target that triggers a video overlay using MindAR and A-Frame. I want to place a button on top of the video overlay at a specific location, and the goal is to play an audio file when this button is pressed.
While I can see the overlay video and the button correctly positioned, the button is not clickable. It seems that the video overlay might be intercepting the click events, or the button is not receiving the click events as expected.
How can I make the button clickable over the video overlay? Below is my code:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AR Video Overlay with Audio Toggle</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mind-ar@1.2.1/dist/mindar-image- 
     aframe.prod.js"></script>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
        .a-enter-vr { display: none; }
        #debugInfo {
            position: fixed;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-family: monospace;
            z-index: 1000;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="debugInfo"></div>

    <a-scene mindar-image="imageTargetSrc: ./targets.mind;" color-space="sRGB" 
    renderer="colorManagement: true, physicallyCorrectLights" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" 
    device-orientation-permission-ui="enabled: false">
        <a-assets>
            <video id="mainVideo" src="./ram.mp4" preload="auto" loop></video>
            <audio id="audio1" src="./audio2.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
        </a-assets>

        <a-camera position="0 0 0" look-controls="enabled: false">
            <a-entity cursor="fuse: false; rayOrigin: mouse;" raycaster="objects: 
    .clickable"></a-entity>
        </a-camera>

        <a-entity mindar-image-target="targetIndex: 0">
            <a-video src="#mainVideo" position="0 0 0" rotation="0 0 0" width="1" 
    height="1.26" play-on-click></a-video>
            
            <!-- Toggle Audio Button -->
            <a-entity position="-0.04 0.34 0.05" class="clickable" audio-control>
                <a-circle radius="0.05" material="color: #00FFFF; opacity: 0.7; emissive: 
    #00FFFF; emissiveIntensity: 0.5;"></a-circle>
                <a-text value="Toggle Audio" align="center" position="0 0 0.01" scale="0.05 
    0.05 0.05" color="#000000"></a-text>
            </a-entity>
        </a-entity>
    </a-scene>

    <script>
        const mainVideo = document.querySelector("#mainVideo");
        const audio1 = document.querySelector("#audio1");
        const debugInfo = document.querySelector("#debugInfo");

        function updateDebugInfo(message) {
            debugInfo.innerHTML += message + "<br>";
            console.log(message);
        }

        function toggleAudio() {
            if (audio1.paused) {
                audio1.play();
                updateDebugInfo("Audio started playing");
            } else {
                audio1.pause();
                updateDebugInfo("Audio paused");
            }
        }

        AFRAME.registerComponent('play-on-click', {
            init: function () {
                this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
                this.el.addEventListener('click', this.onClick);
                updateDebugInfo("Video click listener added");
            },
            onClick: function (evt) {
                mainVideo.play();
                updateDebugInfo("Video play triggered");
            }
        });

        AFRAME.registerComponent('audio-control', {
            init: function () {
                this.el.addEventListener('click', toggleAudio);
                updateDebugInfo("Audio button click listener added");
            }
        });

        const sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');

        sceneEl.addEventListener("arReady", (event) => {
            updateDebugInfo("MindAR is ready");
        });

        sceneEl.addEventListener("arError", (event) => {
            updateDebugInfo("MindAR failed to start");
        });

        sceneEl.addEventListener("targetFound", event => {
            updateDebugInfo("Target found");
            mainVideo.play();
        });

        sceneEl.addEventListener("targetLost", event => {
            updateDebugInfo("Target lost");
            mainVideo.pause();
        });

        // Ensure audio can play on mobile devices
        document.addEventListener('click', function() {
            audio1.play().then(() => {
                audio1.pause();  // Immediately pause after enabling audio
                updateDebugInfo("Audio enabled");
            }).catch(e => {
                updateDebugInfo("Audio enable failed: " + e);
            });
        }, { once: true });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

